# Padronização de nomenclatura de "String Resources"

Tags: android

Para suportar internacionalização, o *Android* possui arquivos de "recursos" chamado de `resource` em XML, contendo os textos a serem exibidos na aplicação.  Por padrão, o arquivo `/res/values/strings.xml` possui os textos de uma aplicação Android.
Exemplo:

```
<string name="str_titulo">Nome</string>
```

Cada `string` dentro do XML é compilada e associada um `id` como mostra no [String Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html). Estes `ids` são colocados em um arquivos de recursos, `R`, como variáveis `public static final`. É possível atribuir qualquer `chave` para cada *string*, porém esta chave é criada mornamente sem uma padronização definitiva, por exemplo:

- `str_titulo_nome`: nome
- `str_actionbar_titulo_nome`: nome
- `str_toolbar_titulo_nome`: nome

A API Android já traz nativamente e inclusive incentiva a utilização de `resources` externos para exibição dos textos da aplicação, tornando mais fácil o trabalho de internacionalização. Por padrão o arquivo `string.xml` fica na pasta `values` e é possível inserir uma outra língua criando outro diretório por exemplo: `values-es`, que seria do idioma Espanhol.

#### Dúvida

Existe uma padronização da nomenclatura atribuída às `String Resources` que é definido para melhoria de entendimento e clareza na codificação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Que eu saiba não existe qualquer tipo de padronização indicada pela google.
No entanto, podem-se encontrar algumas "best practices" dispersas na documentação:

- Nomes de icons - Icon Design Guidelines, [design tips.](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#design-tips)
- Nomes de pastas - Providing Resources, [Qualifier name rules.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#QualifierRules)

O que é imposto é que os nomes podem apenas incluir caracteres minúsculos `a-z`, numéricos `0-9`, *underscore* `_` ou ponto `.`.

Aqui, ou na criação de qualquer outro tipo de nome, deve-se ser consistente e descritivo.

Eu poderia colocar aqui a forma como faço, como tento ser consistente e descritivo, mas, e principalmente no que diz respeito a ser descritivo, isso depende um pouco de cada um.

Talvez uma boa fonte de inspiração seja a [classe R](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#design-tips) do SDK.

Comment: Como disse ali na resposta do nosso amigo o ponto `.` tenho um pouco de "preconceito" de usar porque quando eu uso o `getString(R.string.bla.bla)` dentro da `classe`, o Android reconhece apenas `R.string.bla` e ignora tudo que estiver na frente. Tenho usando o _underscore_ para separar cada `label`.

Comment: O ponto só deve ser usado para indicar o inicio da extensão do arquivo, no caso de *resources* em arquivos

Comment: Sendo assim, a resposta do Leonardo Dias não é válida?

Comment: O exemplo apresentado não é válido pela razão apontada por você.

Answer (score 3):

Eu acredito que um padrão oficial realmente não exista.

Eu procuro sempre antes de iniciar a nomenclatura, definir qual o objetivo da mensagem, por exemplo:

```
<string name="error.message.network">Network error</string>
<string name="error.message.call">Call failed</string>
<string name="error.message.map">Map loading failed</string>
```

E separo por blocos, conforme os objetivos das mensagens.

Comment: Não acho interessante usar "ponto" para separar cada `label`, pois quando é chamado dinamicamente usando `getString` ele acontece erro: `The primitive type int of R.string.bla.bla.bla does not have a field teste`

Comment: Sigo o mesmo padrão de ponto e ao usar dinamicamente você utiliza _ ao invés dos pontos.

Answer (score 2):

Como o código já trará "@string/", identificando que se trata de uma string, eu optei por identificar as strings apenas com as abreviações dos objetos, que já apresentam uma certa padronização no mercado, seguidas por um nome, como:

- btn_play
- btn_register
- btn_save
- txt_result (txt pra mim em geral não se posiciona ao lado de campo editável)
- txt_title
- txt_instruction
- lbl_name (lbl é txt, mas identifica em geral um campo editável)
- lbl_address
- lbl_zipcode etc

O código fica enxuto e explicativo (ex: (@string/btn_play).

Assim, aproveito para dar nomes significativos, sem torná-los tão longos, podendo identificar de pronto o tipo de objeto (ou widget) em questão.

Ademais, "str_", na minha opinião, geraria pleonasmo desnecessário no código, vejamos:

@string/str_......

Espero que esta contribuição ajude.

Bons estudos!!!

siomara.com.br